# Anaconda Navigator Install Issues for RStudio

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I recommended to my class (2 sections) that they use Anaconda Navigator for a quick and easy way to install both python and R on their machine.  I have had success with this recommendation in the past but recently this proved to be very problematic.  At least on macOS, installing RStudio via the GUI does not work.  It appears to stall.

In addition, attempting to create a new environment ,with both R and Python (3.7), the environment does not get created.  It appears in the GUI for < second and then goes away without any other warning visible to the student.

Is there a bug in the recent version or perhaps version collisions across the environments?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a bug. I installed Anaconda navigator, then RStudio in navigator. RStudio installed, but when I relaunch navigator I don't get the 'launch' tile, only the 'install' tile for RStudio. When I click the install tile (just to humor myself I suppose) it appears that it is reinstalling RStudio, but really it's just a hung process.

My environment is Windows 10 1909